# Android get Location in Button click

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I try to get the location in button click. I wrote `LocationListener` method and everything working perfect.This is my source

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        editLocation.setText("");
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                    + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);

        /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "
            + cityName;
        editLocation.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

I can check latitude and longitude with `LocationListener`, but how i can get current location in button click ?

Comment: you can make latitude and longitude global ....so you can use it in any other function...

Comment: How ? @rafsanahmad007

Comment: The best way is to use a callback that will notify you when location is acquired; sometimes you cannot just expect to get it when you demand for it - like ordering from a fast food restaurant

Answer (score 1):

You are getting it from [LocationManager::getLastKnownLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code its working for my App. You can try it to fetch the Location.

```
 ro_gps_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RODetailsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RODetailsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, (LocationListener) RODetailsActivity.this);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            if (location == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (location != null) {
                Log.e("locatin", "location--" + location);

                Log.e("latitude at beginning",
                        "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + location.getLatitude());
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
        }
    });
```

and method for getting the data.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Log.e("latitude", "latitude--" + latitude);
    try {
        Log.e("latitude", "inside latitude--" + latitude);
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

            ro_gps_location.setText(state + " , " + city + " , " + country);
            ro_address.setText(address + " , " + knownName + " , " + postalCode);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```